# Which grows faster? $(ax)!$ or $x^x$?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, factorial, infinity

Messing around on wolphramalpha I found that:

> $\lim_\limits{x \to\infty} \dfrac { x !}{x^x} = 0\;$ and $\;\lim_\limits{x \to\infty} \dfrac { (2x) !}{x^x} = \infty$

testing with a few more values I found:

> $\lim_\limits{x \to\infty}\!\dfrac { (1.000001 x) !}{x^x}\!=\!0\;$ and $\;\lim_\limits{x \to\infty}\!\dfrac { (1.000002 x) !}{x^x}\!=\!\infty$

I was wandering: if it exists, what is the number $a$ such that $\lim_\limits{x \to\infty} \dfrac { (ax) !}{x^x} = 1\;?\;$ And if it doesn't exist, what is the number $a$ such that:

> if $\,b > a\,,\;\;\lim_\limits{x \to\infty} \dfrac { (bx) !}{x^x} = 0$ 
> if $\,c < a\,,\;\;\lim_\limits{x \to\infty} \dfrac { (cx) !}{x^x} = \infty$

and how could someone calculate this ?

Comment: Try using Stirling formula, it should work

Comment: Stirling's formula says$$n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$

Comment: I suspect that the true answer is 1, and that the Wolfram Alpha computation saying otherwise is from a rounding error or some other bug.

Comment: I don't understand, you're multiplying your limit by a constant, which should only scale the limit if the limit already exists. But yours jump from zero to infinity

Comment: Hint: if it did exist then $1.000001<a<1.000002$ which is highly unlikely

Comment: Rather than the usual approximation, you can use strict inequalities $\sqrt{2\pi} n^{n+1/2} e^{-n+1/(12n+1)} < n! < \sqrt{2\pi} n^{n+1/2} e^{-n+1/(12n)}.$  See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html

Comment: @DavidK it was out of the argument of the factorial function, but it seems to be edited since then.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz The constants $1.000001$ and $1.000002$ were outside, but in all other cases the constant was inside. Since these were allegedly results from WolframAlpha, the most likely explanation was that the right parenthesis had been misplaced when transcribing those two cases. In any case the incorrect notation has been cleaned up now.

Comment: [This limit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+x-%3Einfty+%281.00000200000001x%29%21%2Fx%5Ex) is correct and [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+x-%3Einfty+%281.000002000000001x%29%21%2Fx%5Ex) also gives $\infty$ for WolframAlpha.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Wait ... you're saying that if you *increase* the constant $a$ from $1.000002000000001$ to $1.00000200000001$ (have to count those places carefully), the limit goes from $\infty$ to zero?

Comment: @DavidK It is a problem [with WolframAlpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seCBN.jpg). I am not saying the right most link has a true result

Comment: @TymaGaidash The result that I question actually is the leftmost link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that
$$
\sqrt{2\pi}\; n^{n+1/2} e^{-n+1/(12n+1)} < n! < \sqrt{2\pi}\; n^{n+1/2} e^{-n+1/(12n)}.
$$
(See formula $(26)$ on https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html).
Therefore
$$
\sqrt{2\pi}\; (ax)^{ax+1/2} e^{-ax+1/(12ax+1)} < (ax)!
 < \sqrt{2\pi}\; (ax)^{ax+1/2} e^{-ax+1/(12ax)}.
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{2\pi}\; a^{ax+1/2} x^{(a-1)x+1/2} e^{-ax+1/(12ax+1)} < \frac{(ax)!}{x^x}
 < \sqrt{2\pi}\; a^{ax+1/2} x^{(a-1)x+1/2} e^{-ax+1/(12ax)}.
$$

Regrouping the terms,

$$
\sqrt{2\pi a}\; \left(\frac{a^a x^{a-1}}{e^a}\right)^x x^{1/2} e^{1/(12ax+1)}
 < \frac{(ax)!}{x^x}
 < \sqrt{2\pi a}\; \left(\frac{a^a x^{a-1}}{e^a}\right)^x x^{1/2} e^{1/(12ax)}.
$$

Now we know that $\dfrac{(ax)!}{x^x} > 0$ for $x > 0,$ so if you can prove that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{2\pi a}\; \left(\frac{a^a x^{a-1}}{e^a}\right)^x x^{1/2} e^{1/(12ax)} = 0
$$
for a particular value of $a,$ then by the squeeze theorem you can prove that
$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{(ax)!}{x^x} = 0.$
I think you will find that this is an easy proof if $a = 1.$

On the other hand, if (for some value of $a$) you can prove that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \sqrt{2\pi a}\; \left(\frac{a^a x^{a-1}}{e^a}\right)^x x^{1/2} e^{1/(12ax+1)} = \infty
$$
then you can prove that
$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{(ax)!}{x^x} = \infty.$
In order to do this, you may find it helpful to consider whether there exists
a number $x_0$ such that whenever $x > x_0,$
$$
\frac{a^a x^{a-1}}{e^a} > 2.
$$
(There's nothing special about $2$ here; you could use any real constant greater than $1.$)
Also note that if $a > 1$ then $a - 1$ is a positive number,
although possibly a very small one.
So $x_0$ might be very, very large indeed.......

Comment: Does it mean that $\lim_\limits{x \to\infty}\dfrac { (1.000001 x) !}{x^x}=0\;$ is an error of https://www.wolframalpha.com/ ? Actually, $\lim_\limits{x \to\infty}\dfrac { (ax) !}{x^x}=\infty\,,\,$ for any $a>\!1$ ?

Comment: @Angelo I think yes, that is what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $\frac{(cx)!}{x^x}$.

If you let $c = 1+\frac{1}{n}$, and $x = \exp(dn)$, then the expression becomes very large very quick as soon as $d > 1$.

Now with $c=1.000001$ and $n = 1,000,000 x$ would be a number with several hundred thousand digits, and for $x^x$ the number of digits has several $100,000$ digits. So I think we can forgive wolfram for not getting the right result. You’d probably need to ask wolfram engineers about what exactly is going on.